# Bokeh - Vbar plot with off-centered bars

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am trying to do a Bokeh bar plot for two sets of data with different scales, so with different y-axis.
I have managed to plot the twin axis, but I see the two different bar plots one above the other. They are more or less visible if I put an alpha value of 0.5, but still I would like to have the two sets of bars next to each other, like in the typical bar plots.

In summary, I have this:

[image: adsfadf]

But I would like to have something like this (with my twin axis and my data, the image is just an example), with bars next to each other per month and my twin axis:

[image]

Is there a way to move the bars to the right/left side of the x-axis cursor? Or just to show half of the bar?

The code I'm using is the following:

```
p = figure(title=title, plot_width=1000, plot_height=350,
                   x_range=months, y_range=(0, max(dataP) * 1.2),
                   tools="box_zoom, pan, reset, hover, save", active_drag='box_zoom')

p.yaxis.axis_label = 'dataP label'
p.vbar(months, top=dataP,color='blue', width=0.5, alpha=0.5)
p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": Range1d(start=0, end=max(dataI) * 1.2)}

p.vbar(months, top=dataI, color="red", y_range_name="foo", width=0.7, alpha=0.5)
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo", axis_label="dataI label"), 'right')
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#userguide-categorical-bars-grouped-dodged

Comment: @bigreddot I can't believe I haven't found that earlier... That solved my problem, thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad you got things working, please consider self-answering with details of your solution for the benefit of others.

Comment: The page does not exist anymore, but I am interested in the same topic.